# Can I do a multi key join in sql?

Tags: sql

Need some help with this query. I'm trying to create a query which selects all parent details and I have another table to attach which is called Family. The problem I have is that the Family table contains a FamilyListID field which contains the primary keys for Pupil and Parents separated via carriage return. Of course there may be be several ID's in there as the Pupils may have siblings so this is all stored in this field.

Is there a way I can join multi Pupil.pk_PupilID, Father.pk_PersonID, Mother.pk_PersonID to relate to Family.FamilyListID, bearing in mind that there may not be Father.pk_PersonID or a Mother.pk_PersonID depending on the circumstance of the pupil. Hope that makes sense - I know there needs to be a join table realistically between family and pupil but this is the structure I currently have to work with.

```
SELECT 
    Pupil.pk_PupilID, Pupildata.Title, Pupildata.Forename, 
    Pupildata.Surname, Pupildata.PreferredForename, 
    father.pk_PersonID, father.Title, father.Forename, father.Surname, 
    mother.pk_PersonID, mother.Title, mother.Forename, mother.Surname, 
    Pupil.Form, 
    Address.Address1, Address.Address2, Address.TownCity, Address.Postcode, 
    Address.Country, Address.County  
FROM
    Pupil 
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSON AS Pupildata ON Pupil.pk_PupilID = Pupildata.pk_PersonID
LEFT JOIN 
    RELATION AS rfather ON Pupil.pk_PupilID = rfather.fk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSON AS father ON rfather.fk_RelatedPersonID = father.pk_PersonID
LEFT JOIN 
    RELATION AS rmother ON Pupil.pk_PupilID = rmother.fk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSON AS mother ON rmother.fk_RelatedPersonID = mother.pk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSONADDRESS AS pa ON Pupil.pk_PupilID = pa.fk_PersonID 
LEFT JOIN 
    ADDRESS ON pa.fk_AddressID = Address.pk_AddressID 
WHERE 
    Pupil.pk_PupilID IN ('" & pks & "') 
    AND rfather.Relationship IN ('Father', 'Stepfather')  
     OR rmother.Relationship IN ('Mother', 'Stepmother') 
    AND Address.PrimaryAddress = 1 
ORDER BY 
    Pupildata.Forename ASC
```

Comment: cross them all and shift the constraint on the where clause - most database will do the right thing and not actually run a cross join

Comment: I have to say that this actually sounds like an issue with the database design.  Having multiple keys in a single text field, separated by carriage returns, completely breaks the purpose of the database.  Seems better to have a relationship table that will relate the individual to all family members, or possibly just have a family table to which each is associated.

So, I would put a Family ID on the Person table rather than have multiple Person ID's in a column on the Family table.

Comment: Well that structure is a sure loser for all time, so I would fix it now. There is no excuse for storing data in rows with carriage returns in a field and then wanting to pull out parts to compare to other tables.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: Anytime you post a SQL problem you should mention the database backend as the solutions may be different for different databases.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I've decided to fix the structure properly so that I don't have multi keys stored in a field, and that way I can create the correct relationships and obtain the right data efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is your data structure. You need to pull out the data you need into a temp table that is properly structured and then do the joining or fix your data model. This is how I did this using the split function. There are plenty of these available if you search around for split functions. Choose one that fits your needs the best. I had to replace the CRLF with a `|` because my function only allows a single character delimiter.

If you search around you may find one that will allow you to use the longer delimiter. At any rate this gives you the idea of how to get the data in a usable for that you can join to. This code was written in SQL server. I am not providing the function code because without knowing what database backend you have it is hard to say what would work exactly, this is more to point you in the direction of what you need to do.

```
Create table #test (Familyid int, Detail varchar(100))
insert into #test(Familyid, Detail)
values (1, '1 '+char(13)+char(10)+ '2 ' +char(13)+char(10)+ '3')
,(2, '4 '+char(13)+char(10)+ '5 ' +char(13)+char(10)+ '6')
,(3, '7 '+char(13)+char(10)+ '8 ')
select * from #test

update #test 
set detail = replace (detail, char(13)+char(10), '|')


select t.familyid, cast(splitdata as Int) as ID
into #test2
from #test t
cross apply dbo.fn_Split_String (detail, '|')

select * from #test2
```

Now the real problem though is as your table gets larger, this is going to be dirt slow as you will have to convert the whole table each time you run the query. This is why this structure is a loser that you need to fix not live with.

If you can't replace this table, see if you can create another table that is properly designed, use the split function you choose and populate it, then keep it populated with triggers on the original tablet that will update, delete or insert to the second table as records are changed in the original table. That is a compromise solution but at least then you only have to do the splitting on a record only when the data changes rather than every time you run the query.